# I want to insert an ID for every existing ROW with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-office

I have a table with different columns (all with data), the problem I have is that I want to assign an ID for every row and I don't know how to do it.

I tried to do with a cursor, but I do not have any condition to distinct the rows, cause in every row some data will be in other rows.

Example of what I want to do:

```
TABLE RACE
___________

COLUMNS
___________

Circuit | Date | Pilots
Montmelo| 10/12| 24
Montmelo| 10/13| 24
Montmelo| 10/14| 24
Japan   | 10/17| 23
```

This is just an example of a table, and what I want is add an ID for every row, increased by 1

```
TABLE RACE
___________

COLUMNS
___________

Circuit | Date | Pilots | ID
Montmelo| 10/12| 24     | 1
Montmelo| 10/13| 24     | 2
Montmelo| 10/14| 24     | 3
Japan   | 10/17| 23     | 4
```

Hope you understand me, and sorry for my English!

Comment: Does the order of the ID matter? If not I would suggest Identity column.

Comment: Could you please supply the criteria by which these IDs should be applied? If it is arb, use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`

Comment: Do you want to change the table structure or just select the results with an extra calculated column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afbf6f/6/1) is what i've worked out. Turns out you can use the IDENTITY to count rows like that. 
So thats:

```
ALTER TABLE RACE ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jeyem, You can easily add an `ID` column using `ROW_NUMBER`. Like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Circuit varchar(20), Date VARCHAR(8), Pilots int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable
SELECT 'Montmelo', '10/12', 24  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Montmelo', '10/13', 24  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Montmelo', '10/14', 24  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Japan', '10/17', 23 

SELECT *, ID=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Date)
FROM
    @MyTable
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! But this is ordered by Date, if some race has the same Date it will print the same ID, what i want to do is independently of the data of every row add an ID increased by 1, thanks!

Comment: Which requires you to have one column which has completely unique entries (such as a Primary Key)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
ALTER TABLE RACE ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1);
                 OR
select Circuit,Date,Pilots,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1 ))  as ID From RACE
```